# how to use useEffect and useContext with fetching data?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, use-context, createcontext

I'm trying to use React's Context API as well as Hooks with fetching data.

I'm coding [createContext] like below, but it doesn't work.

```
import { createContext, useEffect } from "react";

export const ColorContext = createContext({});

export const ProductsProvider = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/categories')
      const posts = await res.json()
      return { props: { datas: posts } }
    })
  })
  return(
    <ColorContext.Provider value={props.datas}></ColorContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And here're I'm trying to use [useContext].
This's a default header as a component.

```
import { ColorContext } from '../../src/colorContext';
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function HeaderDafault(props) {
  const colors = useContext(ColorContext);
  console.log(colors);
  
  return (
    <header className={`h-10 px-5 flex items-center relative`}>
    </header>
  );
```

}

There's no errors, but there's nothing in console log.
I think the way i'm using [createContext] is wrong, but i can't find my mistakes.

Comment: are you seeing an error?

Comment: There's no error, but I can't see anything in console log.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/categories why it's 3000?

Comment: @Yuzu you won't see anything in the console log, because you are not logging anything. Or rather, you are not assigning anything. The fat the function returns a props object does not mean it automatically gets assigned to your props. You need to create a state via `useState` and assign it in the `useEffect` via the `Dispatch<SetStateAction>` handler. (i.e. `const [data, setData] = useState({})` and then just call `setData` inside the `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not storing the data somewhere after fetching it in the `useEffect` hook.

`useContext` is used along with `useState` to store and provide the data to other components.

Do this instead:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const ColorContext = createContext({});

export const ProductsProvider = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAPI() {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/categories");
      const posts = await res.json();
      setData(posts);
    }
    fetchAPI();
  }, []);
  return <ColorContext.Provider value={data}></ColorContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I edited my code the way you said, but it doesn't work. there's still no errors, but the data doesn't show up in console log.

Comment: I've updated the answer. My bad, we were using an arrow function to fetch the data from the api. But that arrow function was never called.

Comment: Thank you. I collected my code, but there's still nothing in console.log. and a debug tool doesn't stop.

Comment: Then there must be some problem with the network request or data returned from the API. Inspect the network activity from Network Panel of your browser.